# Pandas DataFrame.loc

Tags: python, pandas

Currently, I encountered an issue using the loc method of pandas. Below, I have 2 cases:

Case 1:

```
d[0]=='2021-02-21 00:11:52'
d[-1]=='2021-02-21 07:39:30'

df3=pandas.read_csv(rawdata_file, low_memory=False)  
df2=df3.set_index("TIMESTAMP")                      
df2=df2.loc[d[0]:d[-1],"O6401_STA3_MPO001_F1_Hz":"O6401_STA3_MPO904_F2_SD"]
```

The code above gave me a dataframe as:
[image: firstpicture]

```
df2.loc[d[0],:]
```

The loc method above would yield the desired output as:

```
O6401_STA3_MPO001_F1_Hz    75.81032
O6401_STA3_MPO002_F1_Hz    75.40068
O6401_STA3_MPO003_F1_Hz    75.04584
O6401_STA3_MPO004_F1_Hz    74.70482
O6401_STA3_MPO005_F1_Hz      -99995
                             ...   
O6401_STA3_MPO552_F2_SD     98.9365
O6401_STA3_MPO901_F2_SD    179.2276
O6401_STA3_MPO902_F2_SD      -99995
O6401_STA3_MPO903_F2_SD     31.8591
O6401_STA3_MPO904_F2_SD     31.7491
Name: 2021-02-21 00:11:52, Length: 312, dtype: object
```

Case 2:

```
d[0]=='2021-02-21 00:11:52'
d[-1]=='2021-02-21 07:39:30'

df3=pandas.read_csv(dat_file, low_memory=False) 
df2=df3.set_index("TIMESTAMP")                    
df2=df2.loc[d[0]:d[-1],'O6401_STA3_NB_Reference'] 
df2
```

Instead of the output as case 1, the code above gave me a dataframe:
[image: dataframe picture for case 2]

I expected the code in case 2 would give the same object type output as case 1. Can someone shed a light regarding this issue ?

Comment: your case1 `df2=df2.loc[d[0]:d[-1],"O6401_STA3_MPO001_F1_Hz":"O6401_STA3_MPO904_F2_SD"]`, you are selecting a range `O6401_STA3_MPO001_F1_Hz":"O6401_STA3_MPO904_F2_SD"`..
But in your case 2, selection range is different

Comment: Indeed, but the concept should be the same as I expected it would give me an object data type with values ranged from 2021-02-21 00:11:52 to 2021-02-21 07:39:30. Then, I can use list method to record those values as [4,4,...,2,4].